# Is it possible to insert a PDF into a Word mail merge using C#

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word, office-interop

I need to print one or more PDF brochures with each letter in a Word mail merge (based on the value of a field in the source query from SQL Server). Is this possible? Or is there another way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Microsoft Word Add-In ([dox42](http://www.dox42.com)) to do this.

There is a ([sample template](http://www.dox42.com/SampleTemplates.aspx)) for free download where a school report is produced for a class, based on a Word document and SQL queries. The SQL queries are controlled by parameters (school and class). For each pupil the school report is automatically saved as PDF. I understood, that is what you want to achieve.